# After clicking a button in my application using webdriver, it gives me “your session has been expired” in IE11

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

After clicking a button in my application using webdriver, it gives me "your
session has been expired" in Internet Explorer 11 and I am unable to proceed. I am able to do it manually, though.

This issue is a showstopper.

Is this an Internet Explorer settings issue (for example, some cookie handling) or web driver issues?

I did all security protected mode at the same level.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: add some code snippet regarding your issue.

Comment: Relevant HTML and code trials please

Comment: WebElement element4 = wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginButton']")));
       element4.click();

   d.manage().window().maximize();
   
   Thread.sleep(3000);

    for(String handle : d.getWindowHandles())
        {
               d.switchTo().window(handle);
               Thread.sleep(3000);
       
            WebElement element5 = wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='overridelink']")));
            element5.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: html Code...<input name="button" tabindex="8" class="button" id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login">

Comment: new window....
<a name="overridelink" id="overridelink" href="https://10.150.7.32/dm-web/">Continue to this website (not recommended).</a>